How to import my own python modules in GitHub Actions
I am testing the following GitHub Actions workflow:
name: Run Azure Login with OpenID Connect and PowerShell
on: [push]

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read

jobs:
  Windows-latest:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install --upgrade azure-keyvault-secrets azure-identity azure-mgmt-resource

      - name: OIDC Login to Azure Public Cloud with AzPowershell (enableAzPSSession true)
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
          enable-AzPSSession: true

      - name: 'Get resource group with PowerShell action'
        uses: azure/powershell@v1
        with:
          inlineScript: |
            Get-AzResourceGroup
          azPSVersion: "latest"

      - name: Run python code
        run: |
          python test/test_1.py

All steps except the last one run without errors. Running the python script gives me an error when import project files from other folders, while locally on my PC it runs without problems:

0s
Run python test/test_1.py
  python test/test_1.py
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  env:
    pythonLocation: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.11.9\x64
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.11.9\x64/lib/pkgconfig
    Python_ROOT_DIR: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.11.9\x64
    Python2_ROOT_DIR: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.11.9\x64
    Python3_ROOT_DIR: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.11.9\x64
    AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT: 
    AZUREPS_HOST_ENVIRONMENT: 
  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\repo\repo\test\test_1.py", line 9, in <module>
    from code.data.constants import DATETIME_FORMAT
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.data'

The project structure looks like this:
repo/
|-- code/
|   |-- data/
|   |   |-- constants.py
|-- test/
|   |-- test_1.py

I looked at similar questions and only found the suggestion to add "_init_.py" files, but it also didn't change anything. I added empty "_init_.py" like shown below:
repo/
|-- __init__.py
|-- code/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- data/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- constants.py
|-- test/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- test_1.py

Another suggestion was to add the following at the begining of the file, but also didn't help:
import sys

sys.path.append("../")

Would appreciate other ideas!

So another way:
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))

from code.data.constants import DATETIME_FORMAT


Seems to work now. Thank you!

If your test/test_1.py is a unit test, you must use another method to trigger it
modify your Yaml
            - name: Install dependencies
              run: |
                  python -m pip install --upgrade pip
                  pip install -r requirements.txt
                  pip install pytest
            - name: Run Tests with pytest
              run: |
                pytest -v

Create a setup.py file and organize it as follows:
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()
    
setup(
    name='code',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=requirements,
    test_suite='test',
)


Thanks for the reply! It's actually not a unit test. I made some tests to check the data quality of my SQL tables using Soda Core. Locally it works fine and I get an exit code. I would like to run the same code in Github Actions to be able to schedule the data quality checks on a daily basis.
